# Момент в освобождении памяти в C++ при передаче аргумента в функцию по указателю

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, динамические-массивы, передача-параметров

Такой код вызовет падение программы. Если убрать "delete" в функции, он будет работать нормально. В принципе, понятно, что "delete" освобождает динамическую память, а я создал этот указатель не во время выделения динамической памяти, а во время передачи в функцию одного из элементов массива. Но я совершенно не знаю деталей этого. Не будет ли кто-нибудь добр ткнуть в статью или объяснить чайнику, в чем детально проблема, из-за которой вешается  "delete" и программа?

```
int foo(int* ab) {
   delete ab;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    int **arr = new int* [5];
    for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int [6];
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 5;
        }
    }

    foo(&arr[1][1]);
    cout << "DEATH!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Удалять через `delete` / `delete []` можно только те указатели, которые были созданы через `new` / `new []` соответственно. Вы можете сделать `delete [] arr[1]` или `delete [] &arr[1][0]`, потому что это тот самый указатель, который возвращён оператором `new []`, а вот `delete &arr[1][1]` сделать нельзя, это неопределённое поведение если правильно помню // UPD: ну и да, массивы нужно удалять через `delete []`, как мне напомнили ниже

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. вы пытаетесь выделять и освобождать память вручную
2. вы пытаетесь освободить память, используя указатель, который не был получен при выделении памяти
3. вы пытаетесь освободить память, используя способ, не соответствующий способу, который был использован при выделении памяти
4. количество освобождений памяти не соответствует количеству выделений памяти

Comment: 3. Почему не соответствующий? Вроде тут по всему коду только new/delete, не? // 4. Для простого учебного примера это не очень важно, ОС сама приберёт все утечки :)

Comment: @andreymal `delete []`

Comment: @extrn а, понял, проглядел

Comment: @andreymal Вызовов `new` вообще нет, есть только вызовы `new []`, которым должен соответствовать `delete []`, а не `delete`. 4) утечки памяти при выходе - всегда ошибка

Comment: @VTT 4) Это ваше личное мнение или где-то в спецификации прописано?

Comment: @andreymal А вы где-то видели, что утечки памяти - нормальная ситуация?

Comment: @VTT да, например в коде в тексте этого вопроса ;)

Comment: @andreymal В коде этого вопроса - прорва ошибок, и утечка памяти - лишь наименьшая из них.

Comment: @VTT что не отменяет того, что утечки здесь совершенно не критичны

Comment: Хм, а что именно вы имеете в виду под ручным выделение памяти? Остальное более или менее понятно спасибо. Если не против, укажите пожалуйста на остальные ошибки, чтобы я мог разобраться с этим.